# Loading Joi Schemas From Files

Tags: node.js, joi

I would like to create a way to `read` multiple files, each of which contain the definition of one [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md) schema, and then `load/push` them into an object or array that I can call from my Node app.

Normally, this is done inline in code:

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.string()
});
```

How should I define each Joi schema in one file, and how do I load them such that they are instantiated and usable in the main app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put each schema in its own file like this

```
// save this as carSchema.js
var Joi = require('joi')

module.exports = Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.string()
})
```

Load them with `require` like this

```
// app.js
var schemas = [
  require('./carSchema'),
  require('./bikeSchema'),
  require('./shoeSchema')]
```

Comment: After, how I can to trigger the validate() of one of them dynamically ? `Joi.validate(oneSchema)`

Comment: `schemas[0].validate(someValueObject)`